# Syntax highlighting for commented out javascript?

Tags: comments, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code

In VSCode is there a way to still have syntax highlighting for commented out Javascript? I was trying to read some commented out JS and didn't want to uncomment it just to be able to read it more easily. It would be great if there were a way to toggle syntax highlighting for comments.

[image: screenshot of code commented out and code not commented out]